# How to copy and paste values into a Lookup (multiple values allowed) column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, lookup-column

**Environment**

SharePoint Online
Modern Environment
SharePoint List

**Question**

How can I copy/paste values such as these into a `Lookup` column (with multiple values allowed):

```
LookupValue_A  
LookupValue_B
LookupValue_C
LookupValue_A, LookupValue_B, LookupValue_C
LookupValue_D, LookupValue_E
```

Note:  The above represents 5 rows of data, in the real scenario there are hundreds of rows.

**What I've Tried**

When editing in `Grid View`, I've tried pasting values with various delimiters:

`;#` or `;#;#` or `,`  or `;`

and none of them worked, eg:

```
LookupValue_A;#LookupValue_B;#LookupValue_C
```

and:

```
LookupValue_A;#;#LookupValue_B;#;#LookupValue_C
```

and:

```
LookupValue_A, LookupValue_B, LookupValue_C
```

and:

```
LookupValue_A;LookupValue_B;LookupValue_C
```

I even tried [this solution from 2008](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fdd24922-33cd-4943-8327-6470de839c2b/unable-to-paste-delimited-values-in-quotallow-multiple-valuesquot-lookup-column?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy) (it doesn't work):

```
LookupValue_A;#1;LookupValue_B;#2;LookupValue_C;#3
```

Comment: I have used semicolon as separator and in my case it's working. I have used like "LookupValue_A; Lookup Value_B; Lookup Value 3"  and it works fine without any issue. Which browser you are using

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 104.0.5112.8.  Are you editing in Grid View? And which browser are you using?

Comment: I am also using Chrome and yes I am using Quick Edit in Grid View option to do so

Comment: The behavior is still erratic for me, it doesn't add the last value when I try and add three values separated by `; ` and other times it adds each separate letter in a word as a value.  When in Grid View, are you just double-clicking IN a cell and then pressing `Ctrl + V` and then clicking OFF the cell?

Comment: And I don't know if it makes any difference, but the column in the destination Lookup column that I am referencing is the Title column.

Comment: Are you copying the values in same list across rows OR from one list to another list? If different lists, do you have exact same lookup column settings in both lists?

Comment: At the moment, I am simply trying to copy/paste values into a single cell (Lookup column) from a text editor, so there is no invisible markup or anything on the values I am pasting in.  Microsoft should have documentation on the required delimiters for a multivalue Lookup column but it seems they don’t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I tried and is working for me:

**Parent List data**:

[image]

**Lookup column settings in child list**:

[image]

**Steps to add data in grid view**:

1. Go to SharePoint list & click on **Edit in Grid view**.
2. Single click on Lookup column cell to select the respective cell (double click will not work):

   [image]
3. Copy-paste the value in this format: `Parent 1; Parent 2`. Note the color of pasted value is still black as lookup column values are not resolved yet.

   [image]
4. Click outside of lookup cell or click on Exit grid view. In my case, I clicked on cell in another column. Note the color of pasted value is green now as lookup column values are resolved.

   [image]

**Note**: I have used **Title** column from Parent List in lookup column settings under **Select a column from the list above** and using same column values (Parent 1; Parent 2) to paste in grid view.

Comment: This approach seems to work.  I tested with 3 values and with values that were 1 word with no spaces or three words with spaces (cause I thought the values might be handled differently).  The key seems to be 1)  single click on the target cell  2)  click off the cell in another cell in the same row.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!

Comment: Sometimes I think you are the only person who has been answering SharePoint Stack Exchange posts for the last two years :)  A very impressively certified SharePoint user!  https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/about/

Comment: Thanks for the compliment! Popularity of this forum is decreasing year by year. The number of answers and questions are slowly going down. Check this analysis for some insights: https://spblog.net/post/2021/01/05/sharepoint-development-state-in-2020-story-based-on-sharepoint-stackexchange-analysis-with-power-bi

Comment: It's so sad and demoralizing, I don't know of a better "forum" solution than stackexchange.  I have often wondered why sharepoint.stackexchange.com is so underused - I thought perhaps it could be because SharePoint is limited to private intranets etc, ie if we have questions about JavaScript on stackoverflow we can share examples and code in CodePen or JSFiddle or a Snippet in the post itself, but with SharePoint it is all so 'hidden' and hard to communicate about, so maybe people just can't be bothered trying to understand the questions posted and communicate the solutions :/.

Comment: True, agree with your points. This forum lack many features available on StackOverflow. Also, people should use this platform for Q&A regularly. I like this forum so I try to contribute here as much as possible instead of contributing on other forums.